# ObjectiveC - [self.view viewWithTag] returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, hidden

I am completely stumped and have been researching for days. Probably something really simple that I am missing.

I have a  `ViewController`  which contains a custom `UIView` called GameView, and a `UIView` called buttonBox which contains a "next level" button. What I am trying to achieve is when the level is completed in GameView, it fires a function in my `ViewController` which shows the buttonBox so the user can click the "next level" button. It simply will not work.

I have attempted this in 3 ways, neither have worked:

- Creating an `IBOutlet` in the `ViewController`, connecting it to the hidden `UIView` (and it was definitely connected) and calling `setHidden:NO`.
- Calling the `[self.view viewWithTag:xxx]` and then calling `setHidden:NO`.
- Using `hidden=NO` instead of `setHidden:NO`.

Relevant code for `ViewController` as follows:

```
@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController
@property GameView *gv;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *buttonBox;
-(void) showButtonBox;
@end

@implementation PlayViewController
@synthesize buttonBox;
...
- (IBAction)showButtonBox {
    UIView *uiv = (UIView*) [self.view viewWithTag:999];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Showing box function");
        NSLog(@"%@", uiv);
        uiv.hidden = NO;
    });
}
@end
```

And my custom view:

```
@implementation GameView
...
   dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{
        _loopRunning = true;
        //NSLog(@"Calling main loop...");
        while ([self loopRunning])
        {
             ...
             PlayViewController * pvc = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];
             [pvc showButtonBox];
             ...
         }
@end
```

The thing is, the variable uiv is returning null in `NSLog`, which is obviously why hidden is not working, but I have no idea why. It also didn't work when I was using `IBOutlet`.

Also, current output from NSLog is as follows:

```
2015-11-24 00:18:38.612 ib[12579:1264539] Showing box function
2015-11-24 00:18:38.612 ib[12579:1264539] (null)
```

Thanks in advance.

**Correct Answer:**

The problem was that I was using StoryBuilder to build my UI, but by using the alloc init method was creating a new view controller (which is never shown) instead of correctly referencing the view controller which was being displayed. This is achieved by passing the view controller being displayed to the view in the viewDidLoad function, see below:

```
@implementation PlayViewController
@synthesize buttonBox;
@synthesize gv;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gv = [self.view viewWithTag:777];
    [gv setPlayViewController:self];
}
...
```

Comment: are you sure you have a view that has a tag of 999 and that is inside self.view (and not inside another view thats in self.view)?

Comment: Does your gameview overlapps and is above your button? check in the Visual editor in xcode in runtime and confirm plz

Comment: Can you see the button? is the click registered? what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @Fonix The view is a child of self.view.

Comment: @SahebRoy the game view does not overlap. UIV is returning null, so the setHidden is definitely not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[PlayViewController alloc]init];`

This creates a new instance of `PlayViewController`. Where have you defined your outlets and views?

- In a storyboard? You can't use this initialiser - nothing from the storyboard will be picked up, you have to use a segue or `initializeViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.
- In a xib file? Is it called `PlayViewController.xib`? If not, it won't be picked up by the initialiser. Plain `alloc/init` of a view controller will only find a nib file as described in the [documentation of the nibName property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName).
- Do you really want alloc / init at all? Do you actually want to make a *new* view controller, or is one already on the screen?

From your comments it seems option 3 is the right answer. The `PlayViewController` is already on the screen, `alloc/init` is creating a new instance of it, which is never being put on screen, which never loads any views regardless of storyboards or nibs.

You need to get a reference to the *existing* instance of `PlayViewController`. Without knowing the structure of your app it's not too easy to say how that's done - is it presenting the game view? Is the game view a subview of the view controller's view? You may need to pass in a reference (weak) to the game view when it is created, at `viewDidLoad`, or set up an outlet in the storyboard.

Comment: Hi @jrturton. Outlets and views have been defined in storyboard. Given this, how would I go about using a segue? I am currently using a segue to launch from the level selector screen to the game screen which is referenced in this question.

Comment: Yeah. I can see it. and the GameView is within it. The GameView is the View that wants to fire the function to show the hidden box. It is trying to call the playViewController to do this, but it just isn't working.

Comment: Thanks JRTurton. Your answer makes sense and I think this is definitely the cause of my problem. Let me have a look. Ill come back and update soon. But yes you are absolutely correct with the third bullet. I want to fire a function in the existing controller which is already on the screen, but from within a sub-view of the controller's view.

Comment: yep! You had it. I will update question with answer... Thanks for your help. I am currently porting an Android app to ObjectiveC and am learning things along the way. For the most part it works the same, but this had me stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Man, it's simple. Let's take a look at:

```
@implementation GameView
...
   dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{
        _loopRunning = true;
        //NSLog(@"Calling main loop...");
        while ([self loopRunning])
        {
             ...
             PlayViewController * pvc = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];
             [pvc showButtonBox];
             ...
         }
@end
```

Here we have the issue:

> dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{

I assume, `bgQueue` stands for "background queue", which means this is not served by the main thread (the UI thread).
Having that said, it's quite naive to expect

> [pvc showButtonBox];

to work properly. Just move this code into the main thread. For instance, you can just wrap the aforementioned line of code into a `dispatch_async` on the main queue. That should solve your probem, if your outlets and/or tags are OK. Cheers.

Comment: This seems correct...never do anything related to UI in background queue, have to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` before `showButtonBox`

Comment: I thought this. But I thought I had done this in the showButtonBox function. That is executing setHidden in the main thread, no?... "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()..."

Comment: Then move UIView *uiv = (UIView*) [self.view viewWithTag:999]; inside as well and see what happens.

Comment: This is not correct; you should not be running a `while` loop in the main thread.  The correct answer is to call the UI code *only* in the main thread.

Comment: @trojanfoe, of course not. We're talking only about the cause of the "missing view".

Comment: Although I believe I was already calling it in the main thread, I have still considered your recommendation. Within the main loop I now call the "showbuttonbox" function within a "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()" thread. Same result. Returns null for uiv.

Comment: One more question about: PlayViewController * pvc = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];  [pvc showButtonBox]; Do you actually present "pvc"? If no, then pvc.view is nil, which causes [pvc.view viewWithTag:999] to be nil as well.

Comment: @JarradCutting did u put all code that related to the UI and View inside the main thread? that including `PlayViewController * pvc = [[PlayViewController alloc]init];`. If not work, try remove all your threading code and see if it works? if it don't, probably the problems lie somewhere else